# How can Java be improved so that it no longer needs to perform type erasure?

Tags: java, jvm

The [official Java tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) explains type erasure and why it was added to the compiler:

> When a generic type is instantiated, the compiler translates those types by a technique called type erasure — a process where the compiler removes all information related to type parameters and type arguments within a class or method. Type erasure enables Java applications that use generics to maintain binary compatibility with Java libraries and applications that were created before generics.

This most likely was a pragmatic approach, or perhaps the least painful one. However, now that generics is widely supported across the industry, what can be done in order for us to not need type erasure? Is it feasible with out needing to break backwards compatibility, or if it is feasible, is it practical?

Has the last statement in the quote above become self referential? That is: "type erasure enables Java applications that use generics to maintain binary compatibility with Java libraries and applications that were created with Java versions that perform type erasure."

Comment: The Sun 1.4 was EOL'ed.  IBM still supports 1.4 on their platforms.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: And at least for the platform that sits in my dad's basement, there *is no* 1.5.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not only that but one can purchase extended support for much earlier versions of the JVM as well.  Last I heard though it is quite expensive.

Comment: None of us here possess a crystal ball, thus, it is not answerable.  Perhaps it can be reopened if you rephrase the question from a "Will there ever be..." question to a "What needs to be accomplished for Type Erasure to be performed in a future version of Java"

Comment: @JörgWMittag would that be a platform actually used for production in 2012?

Comment: @maple_shaft, Made an edit. Does that work?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: he develops a software that is intimately tied to (undocumented, private) OS internals, and apparently at least one of his customers still uses that particular OS release. We were discussing strategies for putting a web GUI on that software, but on that particular machine pretty much the only language choices would have been Java 1.4 (which means no Scala, no JRuby, no Jython) and RPG IV. I'm lobbying for a separate Linux box which only accesses the DB remotely ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The end-of-life applies to the Java Development Toolkit and Java Runtime Environment. And only the Oracle (Sun) versions. But it does not apply to applications written by third parties. The intention is to never break code that has ever run on the JVM, thus it's unlikely Java will ever stop doing type erasure.

Of course C# also introduced generics in later version in backward-compatible manner without doing type erasure, but it basically meant duplicating all the collection classes. Which I suppose is what Java designers don't want to do and thus why they chose type erasure in the first place. Without value types the advantage of non-type-erased generics is not that big.

Comment: The OpenJDK team has discussed looking at reified Generics again, timeframe?  Most likely to be looked at seriously during Java 9's timeframe and if it's technically feasible, delivered in Java 10's timeframe.  But this is serious soothsaying on my part.

Comment: Type erasure is done by the compiler, not the JVM. Introducing reified generics would require a new compiler and new JVM, but presumably they would still work with old code.

Comment: @Gabe: Obviously they would be introduced in new release, so there would be new compiler and new JVM. But it also requires duplicating significant part of the standard library, because it would than need generic versions for new code and non-generic versions for backward compatibility. .NET did just that in version 2.0, Java avoided it with erasure. .NET has value types (struct) and first class support for them precludes type erasure. Java does not, so the pressure for reified generics is much smaller.

Comment: Jan: I was just commenting on the fact that reifying generics doesn't automatically mean all old code is broken. I would also add that a `List<int>` would probably make certainly workloads much more efficient than the current `List<Integer>`.

Comment: @Gabe: We don't disagree in that. I just wanted to note the main drawback.

Comment: Is there some reason you actually have to duplicate those types?  Couldn't the JVM be made to treat, for example, "List<Object>" the same as the old "List" class from the perspective of old code?

Comment: @BryceWagner: It could be done so that old code would accept the enhanced list type (it would simply inherit the basic one), but the old code does not contain the information that would be necessary to construct it.

Comment: "Without value types the advantage of non-type-erased generics is not that big." Except with dependency injection, using generics is an enormous headache.